# what is the formula to get 11 months old documents using ms flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, powerapp

I need to get 11 months old document from the library using ms flow. what formuls i should use to get those 11 months old documents.

Any help would be apprciated. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the below formula to get the 11 months date:

```
getPastTime(11,'Month','dd-MM-yyyy')
```

Answer (score 0):

In the **Get files** action, you can set the odata filter to select only required documents.
[image]

A sample formula you can refer to is as below:

```
Modified  ge '@{formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(), -1), 'yyyy-MM-dd')}'
```

Change the **Modified** to the field you like and the number **-1** to the number of days you want to subtract.